# Server cannot connect Azure share by SMB

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, server-message-block

I've setup an Azure file share, which I can connect to via smb from an Azure Virtual Server, as well as my laptop and desktop machines (both running Windows 10). However I have another Virtual Server with another host, which for some reason fails to connect. This other VS is running Server 2012, so should support SMB 3.0.

The error is...

> System error 53 has occurred.
>
> The network path was not found.

I've checked that the share address resolves correctly. I'm not sure what else to check.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, I had previously disabled "client for Microsoft Networks". After re-enabling this it's working fine.